# Laravel sofa\eloquence

Tags: php, laravel

good evening, I write because I have the following problem:
I state that I have already installed the sofa\eloquence package but it seems that it has not been installed and I continue to have this error:

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

Class 'Sofa\Eloquence\ServiceProvider' not found

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

```html
This is my Composer.json

{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "gloudemans/shoppingcart": "^2.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "sofa/eloquence": "^5.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Comment: did you add `Sofa\Eloquence\BaseServiceProvider` to your `config/app.php`

Comment: @Yosef Yes!!!!!!

Comment: try this `artisan clear-compiled && composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @Yosef done and I receive this:                      

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Sofa\Eloquence\ServiceProvider' not found

Comment: it's not finding `Sofa\Eloquence\BaseServiceProvider`

Comment: @Yosef  Where   "Sofa\Eloquence\BaseServiceProvider"??

Comment: ok just to make sure you added this `Sofa\Eloquence\BaseServiceProvider` in the providers array in your `config/app.php` ?

Comment: please try `composer update`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good possibility that you've got `Sofa\Eloquence\ServiceProvider::class` listed in the "providers" array on `config/app.php` but a version of `sofa/eloquence` that does not provide this class.

In Laravel 5.5 it is no longer necessary to add service providers since 5.5 has autodiscovery built in; so likely composer is installing a 5.5 appropriate `sofa/eloquence` package that no longer contains this service provider class. By removing this reference from `config/app.php` it should more than likely fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
composer dump-autoload 
./artisan optimize
```